# Django extends tag makes JS charts not load

Tags: html, django

I am using a base.html file to create a navigation bar to all the child templates.

The problem i'm facing is that this interferes with my JS charts (google charts) by not loading them anymore.  Could anyone shine some light as to why this happens, and maybe a possible fix?

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

       {% block tab_menu %}
 <div class="topnav">
  <a href="/index">Home</a>
  <a href="/index/devops">Devops</a>
  <a href="/index/qa">QA</a>
  <a href="/index/frontend">Frontend</a>
     <a href="/index/middleware">Middleware</a>
     <a href="/index/portal">Portal</a>
  <
</div>
{% endblock tab_menu %}


</body>
</html>
```

child.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "KPI/base.html" %}
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
             google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
             google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(VelocityChart);
             function VelocityChart() {
               var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                 ['Status', 'Number of Tasks'],
                 ['Completed', {{completed_velocity}}],
                 ['Incompleted',  {{incomplete_velocity}}],
                ]);

                var options = {
                   title: '',
                   is3D: true,
                 };

               var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('velocity_chart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

{% block tab_menu %}
   {{ block.super }}

<h2> QA Dashboard</h2>

 <div id="velocity_chart"></div>


{% endblock tab_menu %}
</body>
</html>
```

The code in the base.html file works fine on the other templates, but won't load the charts in the child templates.

Also the charts load fine without the implementation of the nav bar

**EDITED placement of `{% extends "KPI/base.html" %}` in child.html

Comment: That's not the problem, i won't get the error where it is currently placed.... like I said, the problem isnt that the nav bar isnt showing (which is the code in base.html).... the problem is that the charts in the child template wont load when i add the nav bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because nothing above your `{% block %}` tag is getting inserted into the base.html when you extend it. You need to create `{% block %}` tags to encapsulate your scripts to insert them into the base.html.

When you extend the template, everything outside of a block tag gets discarded.

Added an example:

[[base.html]]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    {% block script %}  <!-- add matching block to contain insert -->
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>

{% block tab_menu %}
 <div class="topnav">
  <a href="/index">Home</a>
  <a href="/index/devops">Devops</a>
  <a href="/index/qa">QA</a>
  <a href="/index/frontend">Frontend</a>
     <a href="/index/middleware">Middleware</a>
     <a href="/index/portal">Portal</a>
  <
</div>
{% endblock tab_menu %}


</body>
</html>
```

[[child.html]]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "base.html" %}
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <!--  add block tag (along with endblock below) to insert your script -->
    {% block script %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
             google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
             google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(VelocityChart);
             function VelocityChart() {
               var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                 ['Status', 'Number of Tasks'],
                 ['Completed', {{completed_velocity}}],
                 ['Incompleted',  {{incomplete_velocity}}],
                ]);

                var options = {
                   title: '',
                   is3D: true,
                 };

               var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('velocity_chart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

    </script>
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>

{% block tab_menu %}
{{ block.super }}

<h2> QA Dashboard</h2>

 <div id="velocity_chart"></div>


{% endblock tab_menu %}
</body>
</html>
```